# WPF Slider - snap to 0.5

Tags: wpf, binding, slider

I need help in following: I want my slider snaps to 0.5, but i can not use TickFrequency property because I'm using Ticks DoubleCollection because of non linear scale. Actually I'm using ticks to draw custom tick bar with digits which looks like this:

```
public class NumberedTickBar : TickBar
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        string text;
        FormattedText formattedText;
        int i;
        double step;
        double minStep = this.ActualHeight / (this.Maximum - this.Minimum);
        double currentPosition = 0;
        // Draw each tick text
        for (i = 0; i < this.Ticks.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0) step = i;
            else step = this.Ticks[i] - this.Ticks[i - 1];

            currentPosition += step * minStep;
            text = "-" + this.Ticks[i].ToString();

            formattedText = new FormattedText(text, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"), FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface("Tahoma"), 10, Brushes.DimGray);
            dc.DrawText(formattedText, new Point(22, base.ActualHeight - currentPosition));
        }
    }
}
```

my Slider definition is following:

```
<Slider Name="SomeSlider" Orientation="Vertical" Style="{DynamicResource MySliderStyle}" 
    Focusable="False" Value="{Binding Path=SomeProp, Mode=OneWay}"
    Maximum="35" TickPlacement="TopLeft" Minimum="8" AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft"               AutoToolTipPrecision="1" 
    MinHeight="80" Ticks="8,15,20,25,30,35" 
    ValueChanged="SomeSlider_ValueChanged"/>
```

As you could mansion, sliders value bound to a Dependency Property, and when I'm trying to do some thing like:

```
private void SLAlowCooling_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)

    {
        (sender as Slider).Value = Math.Round(e.NewValue * 2, 0) / 2;
    }
```

Slider works good when gets manipulated but when I'm changing SomeProp, binding doesn't work. Without event handling binding works fine.

Comment: I think you should do SomeProp = Math.Round(e.NewValue * 2, 0) / 2; in the eventhandler. I suspect that doing what you do clears the binding.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but due to specific task I can't change the value of SomeProp on ValueChange event only on LostMouseCapture..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [solution here](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/SnappingSlider/) (modified it slightly):

```
<Slider Name="SomeSlider" Orientation="Vertical" 
        AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" AutoToolTipPrecision="1" 
        Value="{Binding SomeProp}" 
        TickPlacement="TopLeft" Ticks="8,15,20,25,30,35" 
        Minimum="8" Maximum="35" SmallChange="0.5">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <wpfGridView:SnappingSlider/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Slider>
```

```
public class SnappingSlider : Behavior<Slider>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.ValueChanged += AssociatedObjectValueChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.ValueChanged -= AssociatedObjectValueChanged;
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectValueChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        double steps = Math.Round((e.NewValue - AssociatedObject.Minimum) / AssociatedObject.SmallChange);
        if(steps<0)
            return;
        double newValue = AssociatedObject.Minimum + steps*AssociatedObject.SmallChange;
        if(newValue>AssociatedObject.Maximum)
            return;
        AssociatedObject.Value = newValue;
    }
}
```

- You will need a reference to System.Windows.Interactivity for the
  behavior to work. 
  `xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"`
- This makes the slider snap to multiples of SmallChange offset from Minimum

  For some reason it shows an error in designtime `The name
  "SnappingSlider" does not exist in the namespace
  "clr-namespace:WpfGridView".` don't know why tbh.

Comment: Thanks a lot for advice! I think you have an error because of "WpfGridView" - is a link to his project's name space. Make the link to yours name space and paste it like so: 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
and then <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:SnappingSlider/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
but any way, I've try that and it is do nothing :(

Comment: Does it not work for you? When i try it it works perfect and the binding is kept alive.

Comment: Sorry my english is not perfect, i meant it does nothing, so it doesn't work for me, i don't know why..

Comment: Did you set SmallChange="0.5"? Does it break if you put a breakpoint in AssociatedObjectValueChanged?

Comment: Yes sure a set a SmallChange to 0.5 but for some reason it doesn't break on breakpoint..

Comment: Did you remove ValueChanged="SomeSlider_ValueChanged"? 

Did you add `xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"`

Comment: Thanks it works! for some reason i could not add a xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Int‌​eractivity" constructor couldn't find it, but there were no errors when i linked the Interaction.Behaviors to http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008, now i linked it to http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity and it  works! But there are terrible things in a debug folder :) Any way it works. Thanks a lot!